Hegel's Notion of beauty and it's connection to "freedom"
can someone PLEASE make sense of this for me
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-aesthetics/
"In Hegel’s view, this sensuous expression of free spirit constitutes beauty. The purpose of art, for Hegel, is thus the creation of beautiful objects in which the true character of freedom is given sensuous expression."
if a talented artist paints a picture of a rose (or a rose in nature), how is the beauty in this artwork related to the concept of "freedom" in ANYWAY?!

The artist painting an image of a rose might not experience beauty. The person observing a rose; or an artist painting a rose; or an image of a rose in a work of art; that person also might not experience beauty. Hegel is assuming that the artist and observer experience beauty as the sensual expression of free spirit. When I am just old enough to walk I stumble through green grass in the backyard. The grass leaps and runs with me! This is a memory of beauty and my free spirit. I recover this memory in my early thirties and realize small green tree toads (Spring Peepers) jumped all around me.

There is a whole section of this article explaining how Hegel connects beauty in art to freedom:"Nature is capable of a formal beauty, and life is capable of what Hegel calls “sensuous” beauty, but true beauty is found only in works of art that are freely created by human beings to bring before our minds what it is to be free spirit... the focus of attention is on the human figure in particular... the most appropriate sensuous incarnation of reason and the clearest visible expression of spirit is the human form."

@Conifold i'm more interested in hegel's definition of beauty when it comes to nature, it seems like hegel says ANY beauty has a connection to freedom, including the beauty of a rose in nature which is something that doesn't make sense to me, but even in artwork that's still vague, someone said that beauty helps us escape the everyday struggle so it gives us a sense of freedom and that's what hegel means but i can say the same thing about drugs, is freedom of beauty in artwork the same as freedom you get from drugs to escape from reality of your situation according to hegel?! i don't think so

"Hegel recognizes that art can portray animals, plants and inorganic nature, but he sees it as art’s principal task to present divine and human freedom... Colors and sounds by themselves can certainly communicate a mood, but only the human form actually embodies spirit and reason." In other words, beauty in nature is derivative and inferior. Hegel also thinks that 'genuine' beauty is about content more than form. What do you expect? He is a philosopher of Idea/Spirit that turns the rational into the real through crisp self-awareness, he is not going to validate folk intuitions about beauty.

@Conifold i understand hegel values art above nature because of free spirit and stuff, i just wanted to know whether the beauty of nature is connected to freedom as well and how? thanks for engaging in this conversation though
